# MPI_ALLGATHER error parallelizing code

Tags: fortran, mpi

I'm trying to parallelize the following code.

```
subroutine log_likelihood(y, theta, lli, ll)
    doubleprecision, allocatable, intent(in)    :: y(:) 
    doubleprecision, intent(in)                 :: theta(2)
    doubleprecision, allocatable, intent(out)   :: lli(:)
    doubleprecision, intent(out)                :: ll
    integer                                     :: i
ALLOCATE (lli(size(y)))
lli = 0.0d0
ll = 0.0d0
do i = 1, size(y)
    lli(i) = -log(sqrt(theta(2))) - 0.5*log(2.0d0*pi) &
           - (1.0d0/(2.0d0*theta(2)))*((y(i)-theta(1))**2)
end do
ll = sum(lli)
end subroutine log_likelihood
```

To do this, I'm trying to use MPI_ALLGATHER. This is the code I wrote

```
subroutine log_likelihood(y, theta, lli, ll)
    doubleprecision, allocatable, intent(in)    :: y(:) 
    doubleprecision, intent(in)                 :: theta(2)
    doubleprecision, allocatable, intent(out)   :: lli(:)
    doubleprecision, intent(out)                :: ll
    integer                                     :: i, size_y, diff
size_y=size(y)
ALLOCATE (lli(size_y))
!Broadcasting
call MPI_BCAST(theta, 1, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
call MPI_BCAST(y, 1, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)

! Determine how many points to handle with each proc
points_per_proc = (size_y + numprocs - 1)/numprocs
! Determine start and end index for this proc's points
istart = proc_num * points_per_proc + 1
iend = min((proc_num + 1)*points_per_proc, size_y)
diff = iend-istart+1
allocate(proc_contrib(istart:iend))
do i = istart, iend
    proc_contrib(i) = -log(sqrt(theta(2))) - 0.5*log(2.0d0*pi) &
                    - (1.0d0/(2.0d0*theta(2)))*((y(i)-theta(1))**2)
end do
call MPI_ALLGATHER(proc_contrib, diff, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, &
                   lli, diff, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, &
                   MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
ll = sum(lli)
end subroutine log_likelihood
```

When I try to run my program, I get the following error.

```
$ mpiexec -n 2 ./mle.X 
Fatal error in PMPI_Allgather: Internal MPI error!, error stack:
PMPI_Allgather(961)......: MPI_Allgather(sbuf=0x7ff2f251b860, scount=1500000, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, rbuf=0x7ff2f2ad5650, rcount=3000000, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
MPIR_Allgather_impl(807).: 
MPIR_Allgather(766)......: 
MPIR_Allgather_intra(560): 
MPIR_Localcopy(357)......: memcpy arguments alias each other, dst=0x7ff2f2ad5650 src=0x7ff2f251b860 len=12000000

===================================================================================
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   EXIT CODE: 1
=   CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
=   YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES
===================================================================================
```

Can somebody please explain to me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: You're writing into `proc_contrib(istart:iend)` but you've allocated it to go from 1:diff; ranks 1 and above will overwrite the end of proc_contrib which probably causes the issue.  (There's also a bunch of missing variables; numproc, etc).  Further the allgather tries to read outside the bounds of the array.  You can `allocate(proc_contrib(istart:iend))` and change the call to allgatherv, etc.  Also, you don't really need to do an allgather; an [`MPI_Allreduce`](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/research/projects/mpi/www/www3/MPI_Allreduce.html) will do the sum for you which is all you need here.

Comment: In fact, I'd suggest not modifying the routine, but doing the sum outside.  Ideally, you wouldn't have each processor "know" all the `y(i)`s; they'd just have their own local piece of the problem, call the `log_likelihood` routine, and then allreduce the partial sums (or just reduce if the log likelihood is the final result and it just needs to be printed out).

Comment: 1. The missing variables are all declared as globals outside that subroutine. 2. I understant my first mistake, and i changed to allocate(proc_contrib(istart:iend)) 3. Can you please explain me how to fix the Allgather? I need an Allgather because in my real program I need lli as an output. Thanks!

Comment: As Jonathan Dursi pointed out above, your "diff" argument might vary on with the ranks, namely the last one might have a different value than all the others. To deal with this you'd need to make use of the allgatherv routine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally was able to solve my problem. The serial and parallel versions of my code are available at https://bitbucket.org/ignacio82/bhhh

```
subroutine log_likelihood(y, n, theta, lli, ll)
    integer, intent(in)                         :: n
    doubleprecision, intent(in)                 :: y(n) 
    doubleprecision, intent(in)                 :: theta(2)
    doubleprecision, intent(out)                :: lli(n)
    doubleprecision, intent(out)                :: ll
    integer                                     :: i

do i = istart, iend
    proc_contrib(i-istart+1) = -log(sqrt(theta(2))) - 0.5*log(2.0d0*pi) &
                    - (1.0d0/(2.0d0*theta(2)))*((y(i)-theta(1))**2)
end do
 if ( mod(n,numprocs)==0 ) then
    call MPI_ALLGATHER(proc_contrib, points_per_proc, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, &
                       lli, points_per_proc, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, &
                       MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
    else if (numprocs-1 == proc_num ) then 
    recvcounts(numprocs) = iend-istart+1
    call MPI_ALLGATHERV(proc_contrib, points_per_proc, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, &
                        lli, recvcounts, displs, MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION, &
                        MPI_COMM_WORLD, ierr)
 end if
 ll = sum(lli)
end subroutine log_likelihood
```